# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following in oracle function

Tags: oracle, function, if-statement, plsql

I am writing the below function in which i am getting error as `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new null <an identifier>`. I know this error is coming at the line where i am trying to append if condition with `THRESHOLD_MIN_ALERT` string . I want to append the string `Minimum Threshold` with the if condition and value. So for example for `Minimum threshold` it should come like this if `V_THRESHOLD_MIN_ALERT = Y` then

```
THRESHOLD_MIN_ALERT(Alert Configured) 100
```

If the `V_THRESHOLD_MIN_ALERT = N` then

```
THRESHOLD_MIN_ALERT 100
```

If i remove the if condition then my function runs fine.I dont know the syntax of how to append the if codition.Here is my function:

```
FUNCTION BUILD_ALERT_EMAIL_BODY
    (
      IN_ALERT_LOGS_TIMESTAMP IN TIMESTAMP
    ) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    BODY VARCHAR2(4000) := '';
    V_KPI_DEF_ID NUMBER := '';
    V_KPI_TYPE_ID NUMBER := '';
    V_KPI_THRESHOLD_MIN_VALE NUMBER := '';
    V_KPI_THRESHOLD_MAX_VALE NUMBER := '';
    V_THRESHOLD_MIN_ALERT NUMBER;        

    BEGIN

    Select KPI_DEF_ID INTO V_KPI_DEF_ID FROM KPI_LOGS WHERE KPI_LOG_ID = IN_KPI_LOG_ID;
    Select KT.KPI_TYPE_ID INTO V_KPI_TYPE_ID FROM KPI_DEFINITION KD JOIN KPI_TYPE KT ON KD.KPI_TYPE = KT.KPI_TYPE_ID WHERE KD.KPI_DEF_ID = V_KPI_DEF_ID;
    Select THRESHOLD_MAX_VAL INTO V_KPI_THRESHOLD_MAX_VALE FROM KPI_DEFINITION WHERE KPI_DEF_ID = V_KPI_DEF_ID;
    Select THRESHOLD_MIN_VAL INTO V_KPI_THRESHOLD_MIN_VALE FROM KPI_DEFINITION WHERE KPI_DEF_ID = V_KPI_DEF_ID;
    Select THRESHOLD_MIN_ALERT INTO V_THRESHOLD_MIN_ALERT FROM KPI_DEFINITION WHERE KPI_DEF_ID = V_KPI_DEF_ID;
    Select THRESHOLD_Max_ALERT INTO V_THRESHOLD_MAX_ALERT FROM KPI_DEFINITION WHERE KPI_DEF_ID = V_KPI_DEF_ID;

        BODY := 'ALERT TIMESTAMP : ' || to_char(IN_ALERT_LOGS_TIMESTAMP,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') || Chr(13) || Chr(10);

        IF ((V_KPI_TYPE_ID = 18) OR (V_KPI_TYPE_ID = 19))  THEN  
        BODY := BODY || 'Minimum Threshold' || if (V_THRESHOLD_MIN_ALERT = Y) then '(Alert Configured)' END IF; || V_KPI_THRESHOLD_MIN_VALE || Chr(13);            
        END IF;

       RETURN BODY;
    END BUILD_ALERT_EMAIL_BODY;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the below IF-END IF block:

```
IF (V_THRESHOLD_MIN_ALERT = Y) 
    THEN
      '(Alert Configured)'
    END IF;
    || V_KPI_THRESHOLD_MIN_VALE || Chr(13);
END IF;
```

1. You need to **assign** the value to a **variable**.
2. "Y" is a **string**, and not a boolean value. You must enclose it within **single-quotation marks**.

For example,

```
IF (V_THRESHOLD_MIN_ALERT = 'Y') 
    THEN
      BODY := BODY||'(Alert Configured)';
ELSE
    BODY := BODY|| V_KPI_THRESHOLD_MIN_VALE || Chr(13);
END IF;
```

Alternatively, you could use **CASE** expression:

For example,

```
BODY := BODY || 'Minimum Threshold' ||
        CASE
        WHEN V_THRESHOLD_MIN_ALERT = 'Y' THEN
           'Alert Configured'
        END || V_KPI_THRESHOLD_MIN_VALE || Chr(13);
```

Also,

```
BODY VARCHAR2(4000) := '';
```

**BODY** is an [Oracle keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14354/appb.htm#BABHJHFE). Better use a different name.

For example,

```
v_body VARCHAR2(4000) := '';
```

Comment: when i use decode i am getting the error as Error(1405,45): PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'DECODE' may be used inside a SQL statement only

Comment: @Rahul Sorry `DECODE` is only for SQL and not PL/SQL. Use `CASE` or `IF-ELSE`. See the udpate

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Also change `BODY` as some other variable as suggested above

Change your IF ELSE logic like below.

```
             IF ((V_KPI_TYPE_ID = 18) OR (V_KPI_TYPE_ID = 19))  THEN  
               IF V_THRESHOLD_MIN_ALERT = Y then
                     BODY := BODY || 'Minimum Threshold' ||  '(Alert Configured)' || V_KPI_THRESHOLD_MIN_VALE || Chr(13);
                else 
                     BODY := BODY || 'Minimum Threshold' || V_KPI_THRESHOLD_MIN_VALE || Chr(13);
                end if;
             end if;
```